# Keep DLL module loaded in Explorer until COM class is destroyed

Tags: c++, shell, winapi, explorer

I'm setting a hook to get my DLL module into Explorer's process/thread space, and from there I'm instantiating a COM class that subclasses some windows, sinks some events, etc.

Since my object does everything through subclassing and event sinks, I don't need the hook proc once the object is instantiated.  And I'd like to stop the hook ASAP, in the interest of performance.

The only problem is that unhooking immediately (after my object has just been created) will cause the DLL module to unload, which in turn leads to  access violations and crashing.  So I was wondering if there's an elegant way to unhook the hook, while ensuring that the DLL module stays in memory at least until my object is destroyed.

So far the only solution I've found that works is calling `GetModuleHandleEx` on my own loaded module with `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_PIN`.  This makes sure the module stays loaded for the lifetime of the Explorer process.  But I wasn't sure if that's in poor taste.

Is there any alternative, safe way to make sure the DLL isn't unloaded until after my object does its `FinalRelease`?  (By the way, I don't think calling `LoadLibrary` and then `FreeLibrary` from within `FinalRelease` works. That will still cause access violations.)  Thanks for any input.

Comment: Try calling `LoadLibrary` on yourself this will increase the module reference count  and then call `FreeLibrary` in your `FinalRelease`.  Or write a Shell Extension (rather than hooking) to get into Explorer's address space.

Comment: @RichardCritten - and if **call** `FreeLibrary` instead of *jmp* - crash will be after `FreeLibrary` return to unloaded module. solution exist, but not simply

Comment: How about `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` _"...The function does not return...."_ -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-freelibraryandexitthread

Comment: @RichardCritten - this help only for separate thread - if we have own thread in dll and need unload when thread exit. but this is most simply case. i have solution for generic case too, but not to easy describe it..

Comment: Maybe I'll just stick with `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_PIN`

Comment: possible of course instead direct call `FreeLibrary` - create dedicated thread - and here, after some delay(how big must be delay ?) call `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` but here anyway exist raise - `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` can executed before we return from callback in another thread.

Comment: @user15025873 - i have special [examples](https://github.com/rbmm/LIB/tree/master/CB%20DEMO) how unload dll correct. and key point in [this](https://github.com/rbmm/LIB/tree/master/Ref) and [this](https://github.com/rbmm/LIB/blob/master/WINZ/wnd64.asm), but very not simply

Answer (score 0):

of course after dll set some callback to self ( thread procedure, work item, window procedure, I/O callbacks, etc) - it must not be unloaded, until callback is leave body of dll

of course this is not problem if you set callback in api and callback will be no more called, after api return. so callback can be called only inside api call. for instance `EnumWindows`.

but now let look case, when callback can be called after it set in any time. for instance window procedure

for do this - at first module must have additional reference all time, until callback is active (can be called or inside call)
and after callback return - dereference module. but we can not do this by direct by call `FreeLibrary` (`LdrUnloadDll`) because when we return back to dll - it can be already unloaded

so need instead `call` use `jmp` asm instruction. but this possible do only from asm code. callback stub must be implemented in asm, at begin it must "rotate" stack - swap agruments in stack (if exist) and return address. set return address on top on stack. call "real" callback in c/c++ or other language, and after it returned instead `call __imp_FreeLibrary` use `jmp __imp_FreeLibrary`. `FreeLibrary` of course overwrite return code of callback. but some callbacks really not used return code (say I/O callbacks) . some (like windows procedure) use return code, but not for all messages. usually we do unload when window destroyed and at this last messages return code already no matter. so we can not call `FreeLibrary` after every callback in general case. also LdrAddrefDll/LdrUnloadDll is expensive calls for do it frequently. need use intermediate reference counter inside dll ("fastref") and call `FreeLibrary` only when internal counter became 0. this not damage return code and will be much faster.

also usually callbacks can associated with some object. and live time of this object is longer that callbacks - object must not be destroyed until callbacks is active. so instead reference/dereference dll for every callback (this is not always possible at all. not possible for windowproc callback - because new callback can be at any time - we can not reference dll before every callback) - need reference dll when object is created (inside constructor) and dereference dll when object is destroyed (inside destructor).

first implement fast reference dll procedurs

for x64:

```
extern __imp_LdrUnloadDll:QWORD
extern __imp_LdrAddRefDll:QWORD
extern __ImageBase:BYTE


.DATA?

    align 4
@@UsageCount    DD ?

.code

@@FastReferenceDll proc
    lock inc[@@UsageCount]
    ret
@@FastReferenceDll endp

?ReferenceDll@@YAXXZ proc
    mov eax,1
    lock xadd[@@UsageCount],eax
    test eax,eax
    jz @@AddRefDll
    ret
@@AddRefDll:
    lea rdx, __ImageBase
    xor ecx,ecx
    jmp __imp_LdrAddRefDll
?ReferenceDll@@YAXXZ endp

?DereferenceDll@@YAXXZ proc
    lock dec[@@UsageCount]
    jz @@UnloadDll
    ret
@@UnloadDll:
    lea rcx, __ImageBase
    jmp __imp_LdrUnloadDll
?DereferenceDll@@YAXXZ endp

end
```

and x86:

```
.686

.MODEL flat

extern __imp__LdrAddRefDll@8:DWORD
extern __imp__LdrUnloadDll@4:DWORD
extern ___ImageBase:BYTE

.DATA?

    align 4
@@UsageCount    DD ?
    
.CODE

@@FastReferenceDll proc
    lock inc[@@UsageCount]
    ret
@@FastReferenceDll endp

?ReferenceDll@@YGXXZ proc
    mov eax,1
    lock xadd[@@UsageCount],eax
    test eax,eax
    jnz @@nop
    lea eax, ___ImageBase
    push eax
    xor eax,eax
    push eax
    call __imp__LdrAddRefDll@8
@@nop:
    ret
?ReferenceDll@@YGXXZ endp

?DereferenceDll@@YGXXZ proc
    lock dec[@@UsageCount]
    jz @@UnloadDll
    ret
@@UnloadDll:
    lea eax, ___ImageBase
    xchg [esp],eax
    push eax
    jmp __imp__LdrUnloadDll@4
?DereferenceDll@@YGXXZ endp

end
```

base class for sub-classing with ATL

```
class MySubClassBaseT : public CWindowImplBaseT<>
{
    ULONG dwRefCount = 1;

    static LRESULT CALLBACK StubWindowProc(
        _In_ HWND hWnd,
        _In_ UINT uMsg,
        _In_ WPARAM wParam,
        _In_ LPARAM lParam)ASM_FUNCTION;

    virtual WNDPROC GetWindowProc()
    {
        // force reference/include WindowProc
        return _ReturnAddress() ? StubWindowProc : WindowProc;
        //return StubWindowProc;
    }

protected:

    virtual void OnFinalMessage(_In_ HWND /*hwnd*/)
    {
        Release();
    }

    virtual ~MySubClassBaseT()
    {
        DereferenceDll();
    }

public:

    MySubClassBaseT()
    {
        ReferenceDll();
    }

    BOOL SubclassWindow(_In_ HWND hWnd)
    {
        if (__super::SubclassWindow(hWnd))
        {
            AddRef();
            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    HWND UnsubclassWindow(_In_ BOOL bForce /*= FALSE*/)
    {
        if (HWND hwnd = __super::UnsubclassWindow(bForce))
        {
            m_dwState |= WINSTATE_DESTROYED;
            m_hWnd = hwnd;
            return hwnd;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    void AddRef()
    {
        dwRefCount++;
    }

    void Release()
    {
        if (!--dwRefCount)
        {
            delete this;
        }
    }
};
```

we call `ReferenceDll();` in constructor and `DereferenceDll();` in destructor. so until object (inherited from `MySubClassBaseT`)not destroyed, dll will be not unloaded. also we need replace `WindowProc` to `StubWindowProc` which we implement is asm (because need return with `jmp`)

x64:

```
extern ?WindowProc@?$CWindowImplBaseT@VCWindow@ATL@@V?$CWinTraits@$0FGAAAAAA@$0A@@2@@ATL@@SA_JPEAUHWND__@@I_K_J@Z : PROC

?StubWindowProc@MySubClassBaseT@@CA_JPEAUHWND__@@I_K_J@Z proc
    call @@FastReferenceDll
    sub rsp,28h
    call ?WindowProc@?$CWindowImplBaseT@VCWindow@ATL@@V?$CWinTraits@$0FGAAAAAA@$0A@@2@@ATL@@SA_JPEAUHWND__@@I_K_J@Z
    add rsp,28h
    jmp ?DereferenceDll@@YAXXZ
?StubWindowProc@MySubClassBaseT@@CA_JPEAUHWND__@@I_K_J@Z endp
```

we wrap call to `ATL::CWindowImplBaseT::WindowProc` in `@@FastReferenceDll` / `?DereferenceDll@@YAXXZ` calls. this is need for dll not unloaded direct in destructor, where we call `DereferenceDll();`. destructor can be called inside callback. because at callback entry point we already have at least 1 reference, possible use `@@FastReferenceDll` instead `?ReferenceDll@@YAXXZ`. finally we exit with `jmp` ([*tail call*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) ) to `DereferenceDll`which do nothing (and not change return code) if still exist reference on dll or `jmp` to `LdrUnloadDll` and  never return to dll body (which can be unloaded after this api execution).

for x86:

```
?StubWindowProc@MySubClassBaseT@@CGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z proc
    mov eax,[esp]
    xchg [esp+4*4],eax
    xchg [esp+3*4],eax
    xchg [esp+2*4],eax
    xchg [esp+1*4],eax
    mov [esp],eax
    call @@FastReferenceDll
    call ?WindowProc@?$CWindowImplBaseT@VCWindow@ATL@@V?$CWinTraits@$0FGAAAAAA@$0A@@2@@ATL@@SGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z
    jmp ?DereferenceDll@@YGXXZ
?StubWindowProc@MySubClassBaseT@@CGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z endp
```

here we need first "rotate" stack. so go from

```
arg4
arg3
arg2
arg1
ret
```

to

```
ret
arg4
arg3
arg2
arg1
```

(for x64 not need this, because all args in registers here, but if callback have 5 or more args - this is already need too)

[example](https://github.com/rbmm/LIB/tree/master/CB%20DEMO/ATL) of usage this

Comment: Actually, shouldn't simply calling `CoCreateInstance` on the class keep the DLL in memory for the correct amount of time?  Because then COM will take effect, and the DLL will only be unloaded when `DllCanUnloadNow` allows--i.e., after the object has been destroyed.

Comment: @user15284017 - not all tasks can be resolved with CoCreateInstance . this is only very narrow case

Comment: Well I mean specifically calling `CoCreateInstance` **on a class that's declared within the DLL module**.  Doesn't COM take over then?

Comment: @user15284017 - in this concrete case yes